# Java: Prim's with Fibonacci heap? (JGraphT)

Tags: java, minimum-spanning-tree, jgrapht, prims-algorithm, fibonacci-heap

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/) has a nice Fibonacci Heap class. How can I use it to implement [Prim's minimum spanning tree algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)?

Comment: It this part of a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to write a wrapper class to rename the methods, since (from a cursory look through the JGraphT Javadocs) it doesn't looks like these developers implemented the Queue interface. So you have to write a method called offer that just calls insert, and so on. (Since this is open-source, you should consider making your edits right in the class itself, and sending the project your code when you're done.)